# Cannot import MySQLdb - python - Windows 8.1

Tags: python, mysql, database, importerror

I am trying to import MySQLdb in python. I checked and followed all possible solutions but I am still not able to import it. I have Windows 8.1.

So I started fresh, I installed the latest version of python (2.7.8), set the path and pythonpath variables, and then tried installing the MySQL-python-1.2.5.win-amd64-py2.7  from the link (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/)

This is the error I get

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have tried searching and following many links. Nothing worked!! Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: You said you tried installing MySQL-python, was it successful?

Comment: @Yax - It is a .exe and the installation takes 2 seconds. I dint get any error. Got the Click finish to exit setup wizard message box

Comment: you need libmysqlclient library to be able to insall MySQLdb

Comment: @cgohlke- Following is my Pythonpath variable - C:\Python2.7.8;C:\Python2.7.8\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python2.7.8\Lib;C:\Python2.7.8\DLLs;C:\Python2.7.8\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python2.7.8\Scripts
What should i revert it to? 2) Oh, thats the name of the file that gets downloaded when you click the first link, in PyPi page

Comment: @Peeyush - I googled libmysqlclient download and it took me to the MySQL C Connector. I tried to install it and there was option to only Change repair and remove. Did a change, it updated the libraries and header files. I then tried to import and got the same error. Did u mean Mysql C Connector by libmysqlclient library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue resolved.
I dint have a C compiler / Visual Studio in my laptop - This link might help http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2012/11/is-mysqldb-hard-to-install.html
I installed MinGW - http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/?source=typ_redirect
Selected the c++ option

I uninstalled Anaconda, Python and Installed anaconda again. So python 2.7.7 got installed along with Anaconda. Did a conda init,

```
conda install pip 

pip install mysql-python
```

and then import MySQLdb

No Error!! Hope this helps!!

====================================================================

Update - Jan 2, 2015

If you want to try installing mysql-python package using conda instead of pip, you can try the following, which worked for me.

```
conda install binstar

binstar search -t conda mysql-python
```

This will show you 10 different packages for different OS.
krisvanneste mysql-python is for Win-64

To know more about this package use the command

```
 binstar show krisvanneste/mysql-python
```

This will show you the command to install the mysql-python package which happens to be

```
conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/krisvanneste mysql-python
```

This will install the required package.
Now trying import MySQLdb in python wont throw error.

Comment: What can be the possible reason if going via the second option still gives an error while importing? My installation proceeded fine without any error.