# Cannot import MySQLdb on Windows with Anaconda Python Stack

Tags: python, mysql, module, anaconda

I recently installed mysql-python with these methods but no one worked;

- conda install mysql-python
- pip install mysql-python
- easy_install mysql-python
- I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705890/cannot-import-mysqldb-python-windows-8-1)
- I installed from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

After all installation I am able to see the package in Anaconda\Lib\site-packages and in ipython tab completation works for MySQLdb. However, if I try to import it it raises;

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dd22983d5391> in <module>()
----> 1 import MySQLdb

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Do you have any suggestion to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking if the MySQLdb package is in the search path:

```
>>> import sys
>>> s = sorted(sys.path)
>>> for ss in s: print ss
```

The `Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` folder should appear in the list. If not, you can:

- add the path to the sys.path (just an .append(), as sys.path is a list) in your client program,
- or globally, modifying the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: Strange. I have MySQLdb install but in `MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg`. That seems wildly different from your version (even ignoring it's x86_64 version). Are you sure you install the right package?

Comment: Check eg. this page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5 Seems most people are using the 1.2.x versions, but there is even a 2.x series started.

Comment: Don't sort sys.path. The original order matters.

Comment: @asmeurer as you can see, I just sort sys.path to make it easier to find the path. I never change sys.path itself.